# Bootstrap, css How to change background

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background

I am using this bootstrap:
http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/#
I want to change this white background? 
I've tryed in class `wrapper`, but it changed only background under content, rest od page under it was still white.

Thanks for help :)

```
#wrapper {background-color: red;...}
```

}
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because the body, html and #wrapper height are not set to 100%, so add:

```
html, body { height: 100%; } 
#wrapper { height: 100%; background-color: red; }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not changing all white part, but only under my letters, tables etc.

Comment: Strange, it helps in my tests... try to do this: 
- Set the background-color to html and body first, so set it's height to 100% to see where they are, when this background changes fill all page height, try to do the same with #wrapper, but with another color to see the difference

Comment: With only this: 
html, body { height: 100%;  background-color: blue;}
everything is white. With this values only it wrapper, only a part has a colour

Comment: Are you sure the css file you are writing is making any changes? You can set it to !important just to have sure, but it's not cool to let it in your code

Comment: Yes, I've edited question. But still with html, body it has no effect

Comment: Ok, i would need to see the code, do u want to share your screen by hangouts?

Comment: Ok. Which one hangouts? I've changed slighty nothing from downloaded one

Comment: Google Hangouts, do you use it? my email is eduardochenrique@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the background-color property for body as well as the page-content-wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `page-content-wrapper` class. It will change the background of the white part, but you may want change the color on the body too.

Answer (score 0):

if you inspect the body css are this,

`font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff; //change the color`

Just try to inspect and edit it until you get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently have rules #wrapper and also in the body, try this way:

```
#wrapper {
    ...
    background-color: #eee;
}

body {
    ...
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

I hope i´ve helped.

Comment: So do you know how to fix it?

Comment: try to change only the background-color property of the body. Here it worked